# Save pictures in a specific folder with Java

Tags: java, save, directory, image, fileutils

I'm trying to save the images extracted from a. doc file in a temporary folder.
The folder I was able to create it and also the images were extracted but I have no idea how to save them in the folder.
Can you help?

This is what has been done so far:

```
private static void documentImagesCapture(HWPFDocument doc) {
    PicturesTable picturesTable = doc.getPicturesTable();
    List<Picture> allPictures = picturesTable.getAllPictures();
    System.out.println("Number of pictures in the document: "+allPictures.size());

    if (allPictures.size()>0){

        final Path folderPath = Paths.get("src/test/resources/test-documents/");
        final Path tmpDir;

        try {
            // Create tmp folder
            tmpDir = Files.createTempDirectory(folderPath, null);
            System.out.println("This is a temporary folder: " + tmpDir);

            // Extract a Picture file
            for (Picture pic : allPictures){
                System.out.println("this is the picture that I want to save : " + pic);
                //Save pic in tmpDir???????
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(">>>>>>>>> ERROR >>>>>>>>> WordDocSplitter.documentImagesCapture()");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

---

Thanks David!!!!
I solved in this way:

```
for (Picture pic : allPictures){
    File newFilePic = new File(pic.suggestFullFileName());
    pic.writeImageContent(new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFilePic)));
    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(newFilePic, new File(tmpDir.toString()));
    FileUtils.forceDelete(newFilePic);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the writeImageContent method for the Picture object.  Documentation [here](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Picture.html#writeImageContent%28java.io.OutputStream%29).

> writeImageContent
>
> public void writeImageContent(java.io.OutputStream out)
>                          throws java.io.IOException
>
> Writes Picture's content bytes to specified OutputStream. Is useful when there is need
>   to write picture bytes directly to stream, omitting its representation
>   in memory as distinct byte array. Parameters: out - a stream to write
>   to Throws: java.io.IOException - if some exception is occured while
>   writing to specified out